# Looking for Android dashboard-like widget library

Tags: android, widget

I would like to build an Android app showing a dashboard with many different graphical indicators. Have you already used a library containing these items?
Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance and greetings
c.

Comment: What, exactly, is "a dashboard with many different graphical indicators"?

Comment: graphical items like gauges, thermometers that permit to show in a fancy way different situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could take is to create your gauges and dashboard using **CSS**, **HTML**, and **JavaScript** which would be ***stored locally*** in your application's `assets` folder.  You can then use a `WebView` to display them.

`WebView.addJavaScriptInterface` [(link)][1] will allow you to pass data between your Android Java code and the JavaScript dashboard.

The reason I suggest this is that I think you will find more options for the graphical indicators if you look for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based ones.  Here are a couple examples:

- http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/17-jquery-dashboard-gauges-using-raphael-xhtml-and-css
- http://www.netzgesta.de/gauge/

If this is done well, the user would not be able to tell that your UI is not made with native widgets.  If you decide to go down this path, you may also want to consider using a framework like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to help with the Java <-> JavaScript communications.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Comment: yes, but i would be interested in creating native apps

Comment: To clarify, the CSS, HTML, and JavaScript would all be stored locally on the device in the assets folder, not on a web server.  You still would be building a native application.  Your UI is just presented through a WebView instead of another type of native View widget.

Comment: If you do decide to go down this path, you might also want to look at something like PhoneGap (http://www.phonegap.com/) to help with the Java<->JavaScript interface.

Comment: ok, i'll follow your solution ! Thank you very much and +50 for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Android has a Widget API allowing developers to create widgets that sit on the home screen and present the user with information.  Are you looking for information on how to code a widget or are you looking to just download them?

Comment: no, for this project i would like to realize native apps using indicators, not home screen widgets.